# For each query result add it into a table and give an ID php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need help to insert my query results into another table and give it an id number per every result.

```
$GroupSize = $_POST['groupsize'];

//Connect to the Server+Select DB
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName) or die("Nope");

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

//assign group id to groups created
//insert groupinformation to table from userInformation group Id must increment by every group created

    //$query ="Select RegistrationId from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize;
    $query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation SELECT RegistrationId FROM (SELECT RegistrationId FROM userInformation ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.")";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("query failed " . mysqli_error($con));

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) == true) {
        echo $row[0].'<br>';

    }
```

My table userInformation has a primary key on RegistrationId and a foreign key on RegistrationId in groupInformation. Group Id in groupInformation will generate the ID per result auto incrementally.

I know I need to this with a while loop or a foreach but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

begin to Select what you want like as

```
$ stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT //Select what you want to select\\)
$ stmt->execute()
$ array = $stmt->fetch()
```

After u can insert to a new table like

```
$ stmt = $con->prepare(INSERT INTO groupinformation)
$ stmt->execute
```

Ucan't do a insert into and a select at the same row